# Gmail: Displayed name on email coming from a sender's address book

Tags: gmail

A professor of mine has saved my name wrong on his email address book. He sends mass emails out to the students, and everyone is seeing my name being displayed on the email, as how it appears on the sender's address book (It is showing in Japanese Kanji). Is there a way for me to change this without having to contact him? My name nowhere on my Gmail is being displayed like this. I am the only person on his email list that is appearing this way.

Comment: When he sends an email, it will always appear the way he has it in his address book.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to _email_ the professor and inform him of the mistake. By emailing him, using the correct name, it should be easy for him to make the correction - and he might even be grateful? (As an aside, he shouldn't be sending mass emails that exposes everyone's email address - unless that is the intention?)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to inform the professor of this issue. You can not change how it would appear for others. I'm sure he would have no problem with fixing a typo/misspelling in your name.